# Access protected object in array in PHP

Tags: php, class, drupal, protected

I am trying to access the following and need to get the value of **[vid]** array cell.

```
FieldCollectionItemEntity Object
(
    [fieldInfo:protected] => 
    [hostEntity:protected] => stdClass Object
        (
            **[vid]** => 119
            [uid] => 1
            [title] => My Page Name
            [log] => 
            [status] => 1
            [comment] => 1
            [promote] => 0
            [sticky] => 0
            [vuuid] => 3304d1cf-e3cf-4c5a-884a-4abb565ddced
            [nid] => 119
            [type] => subpage
            [language] => und
            [created] => 1408621327
            [changed] => 1408640191
            [tnid] => 0
            [translate] => 0
            [uuid] => 39145013-6637-4062-96e7-1b4589609c4f
            [revision_timestamp] => 1408640191
```

### I tried the following, but I guess I don't have a clue from here:-

```
  $mything = new myClass;
  print $mything->accessObjectArray();


  class myClass {
      protected $var;


      function accessObjectArray(){
        return $this-> $var;
      }
      //other member functions
  }
```

### Update

I actually only have access to the variable $content which has the following multi-dimensional arrays. All I want is to get the array cell's value of **[vid]**.

To do that, I could print `$content["field_image_title"]["#object"]` but after that it's protected. That's where I am wondering that how can I access this array. I unfortunately do not have access `FieldCollectionItemEntity` to include in my page.

On doing this:- I get the following output:-

```
 print_r($content);


Array
(
    [field_image_title] => Array
        (
            [#theme] => field
            [#weight] => 0
            [#title] => Image Title
            [#access] => 1
            [#label_display] => hidden
            [#view_mode] => full
            [#language] => und
            [#field_name] => field_image_title
            [#field_type] => text
            [#field_translatable] => 0
            [#entity_type] => field_collection_item
            [#bundle] => field_image_collection
            [#object] => FieldCollectionItemEntity Object
                (
                    [fieldInfo:protected] => 
                    [hostEntity:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [vid] => 119
                            [uid] => 1
                            [title] => My Page Name
                            [log] => 
                            [status] => 1
                            [comment] => 1
                            [promote] => 0
                            [sticky] => 0
                            [vuuid] => 3304d1cf-e3cf-4c5a-884a-4abb565ddced
                            [nid] => 119
                            [type] => subpage
                            [language] => und
                            [created] => 1408621327
                            [changed] => 1408640191
                            [tnid] => 0
                            [translate] => 0
                            [uuid] => 39145013-6637-4062-96e7-1b4589609c4f
                            [revision_timestamp] => 1408640191
                            [revision_uid] => 1
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done within the `FieldCollectionItemEntity` to try to make the contents of the protected property available? Creating some new class is not going to do anything to help you access a protected property in a different class.

Comment: Hi Mike, it's basically a pre-made module out of which I am trying to extract the variable. I hope I understood your question. If you want me to put all the output here, I can do that.

Comment: I think you might not be grasping what a protected object property is.  You will not have any way to access it unless the class actually exposes a method to let you get at that property (or provide magic method getter functionality). Have you looked over the methods available to that class to see id one works?

Comment: oh. I see. Well then I can look into the documentation for this module. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what your are doing with this:

```
return $this-> $var;
```

is accessing a property named after what is contained in your `$var` variable which does not contain anything in the scope where it is defined. pass it as a function argument:

```
function accessObjectArray($var){
  return $this-> $var;
}

print $mything->accessObjectArray('vid');
```

but in any event, that won't work either since (as mentioned by @MikeBrant) you have an object in your parent object properties. something like this might work better

```
$o = new FieldCollectionItemEntity() // assumes this will construct the object in the state you have posted it
$o->accessObjectArray('hostEntity')->accessObjectArray('vid');
```

note that the method `accessObjectArray($var)` must be defined in both objects for this to work

---

the idea of a protected property is to prevent what you want to actually happen. But! protected means that only the class **and it's extending classes** can access a value. Make your own class that extends the other one:

```
class myClass extends FieldCollectionItemEntity {

      function accessParentProtectedVars($var){
        return $this->hostEntity->$var;
      }
      //other member functions
  }
```

then your `accessObjectArray()` function will be able to acces the protected property. note that it's hardcoded to access the `hostEntity` object.

but seriously, you may want to consult the creator of the other class and maybe you will devise a way to best manage this. My proposed solution is not that much of a good practice if I daresay.

Comment: Hi Felix, thank you for your answer, I actually don't have access to the class itself. I only have a multi-dimensional variable within which I have to extract my variable. I updated my answer for your to take a look. Again, I am grateful for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

"$this-> $var;"  this mean variable variable, and this  throw php notice undefined variable $var,

you have to use

```
return $this->var;
```

or

```
return $this->vid
```

Comment: that's right, i used it as an example, just edit my comment  to have vid  property

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Drupal members as rendered array in the question looks like Drupal array**

I believe you don't need a new class at all, you only need to get node's objects. So, below one line will work for you.

```
$parent_node = menu_get_object();
```

Now, you can access by `$parent_node->vid`